# How to use a Pan responder to scroll a scrollView (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, scroll, react-animated

I have a pan responder overlaying the whole screen and a scrollview underneath it.

I would like to call the scrollTo() method and using Pan responders X/Y travel positions to scroll.

I am using this Pan Responder example code to create a Y value that can increment or decrement as you swipe up or down on the screen.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder

I don't know how to get myScroll view to listen to this Y value change.
Any help is appreciated. thanks

```
// You should be able to run this by copying & pasting
import { createRef, useRef } from "react";
import { Animated, PanResponder, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
// some refs...
const scrollRef = createRef();
const buttonRef = createRef();

// panResponder Hook
const useScreenPanResponder = () => {
  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        pan.setOffset({
          y: pan.y._value,
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dy: pan.y }]),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
      },
    })
  ).current;

  return { pan, panResponder };
};
// custom button
const ButtonWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <View
      onTouchStart={() => {
        buttonRef.current = Date.now();
      }}
      onTouchEnd={() => {
        if (Date.now() - buttonRef.current < 500) {
          console.log("Actual Press");
        } else {
          console.log("Not a Press");
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};
// long list of text
const Content = () => {
  const data = Array.from(Array(100));
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "orange", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      {data.map((i) => (
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: "black" }}>Some Content</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const { pan, panResponder } = useScreenPanResponder();

  console.log("pan!", pan);
  console.log("scrollRef", scrollRef);

  const scrollToPosition = () => {
    // scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ y: pan.y });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Container taking up the whole screen, lets us swipe to change pan responder y pos */}
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,.5)",
        }}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      />
      {/* A animated container that reacts to pan Responder Y pos */}
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [{ translateY: pan.y }],
        }}
      >
        <ButtonWrapper>
          <View style={styles.box} {...panResponder.panHandlers} />
        </ButtonWrapper>
      </Animated.View>
      {/* Here we need the scrollView to be controlled by the Pan Y pos */}
      <Animated.ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
        <Content />
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  box: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: @Abe yes, please check now